# How to pass empty parameter through $_POST

Tags: php, http

In one of the cakePHP framework's view, I take the parameters given by a user and make an action call. Here is how it looks like:

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Save as PDF'),array('action'=>'view_as_pdf',$_POST['data']['Event']['employee'],$_POST['data']['Event']['project'],$_POST['data']['Event']['from'],$_POST['data']['Event']['to'],'ext' => 'pdf'));
```

The problem appears when *$_POST['data']['Event']['employee']* or *$_POST['data']['Event']['project']* project is not provided.

That makes a proper url like:

```
pdf.com/action/16/77/2014-01-01/2014-01-15
```

Look like:

```
pdf.com/action/16/2014-01-01/2014-01-15
```

What I would like it to look is something like:

```
pdf.com/action/16/null/2014-01-01/2014-01-15
```

Comment: Honestly, your question doesn't make much sense. Why do you want null to be inserted in the URL? How will it look like, as plaintext? Like: `pdf.com/action/16//2014-...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the items in your array passed into the `link` method with ternary operator and check the values. Essentially, you need to set a default value if the POSTed value is not set/empty/what-have-you.

You could do something like this:

```
empty($_POST['data']['Event']['project']) ? 'null' : $_POST['data']['Event']['project']
```

You need to pass a string of null in order for it to be passed as `'null'`. Likely, the underlying code for that `link` method ignores empty parameters.

Doing it this way will give you the `pdf.com/action/16/null/2014-01-01/2014-01-15` url you are looking to achieve.

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks a bunch.